# Laravel Sort shoplist front end

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, laravel-blade

Hi i'm doing a shop for a university project. This is my first course in web development and I don't understand how to sort a shoplist page by an html dropdown select in laravel.

**Frontend Blade**

```xml
<div class="toolbar-sorter">
  <span>Sort By</span>
  <select name="sorter" class="sorter-options"  style="width:150px; "data-role="sorter">
    <option selected="selected" value='comic_name'>Titolo: A-Z </option>
    <option value='comic_name'> Titolo: Z-A </option>
    <option value='price'> Prezzo: Crescente </option>
    <option value='price'> Prezzo: Decrescente </option>
    <option value='created_at'> Ultimi Arrivati </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**Route.php** (This is not the only route of shoplist)

```php
Route::get('/shoplist', 'ComicController@shoplistBase');
```

**ComicController**

```php
public function shoplistBase()
{
    $genres = Genre::all();
    $comics = Comic::paginate(9);
    return view('shoplist')->with(compact('genres'))->with(compact('comics'));
}
```

Comment: Add an on change event to your select. Based on its value, call an endpoint where you filter the data and update the view.

Comment: What is the route and Controller for the form that contains your `select name="sorter"` ?

Comment: @IGP can you explain this to me more this answer. I have few route that redirect to shoplist, each of them send a diverse collection of comic , like comic with a price between two values or in base of a category.

Comment: @ChristopheHubert probably I added ` select name = "sorter" ` before the line was like ` <select id="sorter" class="sorter-options" data-role="sorter"> `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the same route for your sorting:

**Wrap your drop-down in a form**

Make sure to use unique values for each options

```
<form action="/shoplist" method="GET">
    <div class="toolbar-sorter">
        <span>Sort By</span>
        <select name="sorter" class="sorter-options" style="width:150px; " data-role="sorter">
            <option selected="selected" value='comic_name_asc'>Titolo: A-Z</option>
            <option value='comic_name_desc'> Titolo: Z-A</option>
            <option value='price_asc'> Prezzo: Crescente</option>
            <option value='price_desc'> Prezzo: Decrescente</option>
            <option value='created_at'> Ultimi Arrivati</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>
```

**Handle the filter request in your Controller**

```
    public function shoplistBase(Request $request)
    {
        $genres = Genre::all();
        if ($request->has('sorter')){
            switch($request->get('sorter')){
                case `comic_name_asc`:
                    $comics = Comic::orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(9);
                    break;
                case `comic_name_desc`:
                        //..
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            $comics = Comic::paginate(9);
        }

        return view('shoplist')->with(compact('genres'))->with(compact('comics'));
    }
```

Comment: Hi i use different route that use the same sort form, is there any change to do to the form action in this case?

Comment: it really depends on the logic of your application - this is the best I can give with the data provided. Please give it a try fist see if it solves the problem in your question

Comment: thanks but the problem remain as it say Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server